# How can I remove the last character of the last line of a file?

Tags: linux, bash, file

I have this set of lines in a file:

```
{info},
{info},
{info},
{info},
```

and I want the file like this without the last ",":

```
{info},
{info},
{info},
{info}
```

How can I do it in bash? Any idea?

Answer (score 30):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed '$ s/.$//' your_file
```

- First `$` is to tell `sed` to match only last line
- `s` is for "substitute", note the empty string between the two last `/`s
- `.$` is a regex that matches the last character in the file

Note that you can use whatever separator you want instead of `/`, for example you can rewrite the expression:

```
sed '$ s-.$--' your_file
```

Comment: @Joa your're welcome :) Try to understand why it works and let me know if there's something you don't understand.

Comment: doesn't update the file.

Comment: @AlexeyDmitriev Use `-i` flag to change in-place.

Comment: If you want to replace the last "," on the last line with "]" in a json file:
`sed '$ s/.$/\]/' your_file`

Comment: I did not search for this one but your explanation was just great!

Answer (score 1):

In vim, you could use :substitute or :s to do this as well. It's a vim-built in -- you can read about it here
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace

The syntax is very similar to the other posted solution, you'd go into the command mode and type in
`:$s/.$//g`