# remove DOS end of file character from many files in Linux

Tags: linux, svg, sed, grep, find

I transferred millions of generated SVG files from DOS to a Linux box and just realized that there is a ^@ as the last character of each file (the DOS end of file character) which is giving an error when I try to display the SVG file in a browser.

In this question:
[How can I remove the last character of the last line of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33680111/how-can-i-remove-the-last-character-of-the-last-line-of-a-file)

Maroun gives the solution as:

```
sed '$ s/.$//' your_file
```

But when I modify it to look like this:

```
sed '$ s/.$//' *.SVG
```

or

```
find . -print | grep .SVG | sed '$ s/.$//'
```

It does not work.

I would also like to be able to specify that it should only delete the last character if it is the ^@.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong or how to get this to work. The SVG files are in thousands of sub directories so I need to be able to make the change from top to bottom of the tree structure.

Comment: See: [How can I run dos2unix on an entire directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11929461/3776858)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your first example isn't working because it's taking only the last file expanded by `*.SVG`. The second example (the one with the `find` command) fails because you're passing find's output to `sed` instead of the file contents.

Also, if you want to change the files' contents with `sed`, you need to use `-i` so the changes are performed "in place".

You could try this:

```
for file in *.SVG
do
    sed -i '$ s/.$//' $file
done
```

Or:

```
find . -name "*.SVG" -exec sed -i '$ s/.$//' {} \;
```

Comment: Alvaro how do I make your command work only if the last character is ^@ ?

Comment: type up to the period before the second $, after the period type ctrl-v ctrl-m (no space inbetween) then continue typing with the $... this should match the dos line-end as last character of the line

Comment: So it would be: find . -name "*.SVG" -exec sed -i '$ s/.^v^m$//' {} \; 
I tried this in bash and it just put a ^M in the spot (.^M$). But the DOS end of file character is the ^@. How do I get the ^@? I tried ^v^@ but nothing happened.